# How to listen for added nodes in the firebase database

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know how to read data from the firebase database, in my database structure, there is a child with various nodes written and pushed by users. How can I add a listener that will tell me whenever a new node has been added in the child and trigger a notification. Please note I already have a method for creating a notification. I don't want to know the contents of the child added, I just want to know whenever a new child is added. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

For this feature you will need to use Firebase [functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?hl=en) with [Database Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events?hl=en)

You can see an example for this function [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications)

Basically how it works

- You write a function (typescript/javascript)
- You deploy that function into Firebase Functions Since you used
  Database Triggers in your function, the function will trigger
  whenever a new item is inserted inside the node you are listen for
- The trigger for this is    onCreate()
- You will make a notification payload that will be sent to    the user
  device token you stored inside your child node

Comment: Am looking for a way to do this within the android app itself

Comment: You can also use ChildEventListener to listen for childs added to a certain node https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener